# Ecipse : MainActivity-CordovaLib Could not find MainActivity-CordovaLib.apk

Tags: eclipse, cordova

I did an update SDK build tools and now I am getting the following error:
[2015-12-09 10:22:01 - MainActivity-CordovaLib] Could not find MainActivity-CordovaLib.apk!

Any ideas ?

I ended up importing my project into android studios and running it from there. I would still like to know how to solve this issue for eclipse though.

Comment: Do you still have a solution for this?

Comment: @marionmaiden, Sorry mate , I just ended up importing my entire project into Android studio and washing my hands of eclipse for the time being.